# Why is the lifetime of a ticket sent in plaintext

Tags: kerberos

I was reading [this description about how Kerberos works.](http://www.roguelynn.com/words/explain-like-im-5-kerberos/)

I am a bit puzzled by this part:

[image]

Why are we sending the lifetime of the Ticket for the HTTP service in plaintext?

That would mean that anyone with access to the network can find out what services we are using and for how much time. That doesn't sound like great privacy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description you read is wrong.  There is no plaintext lifetime in the initial Kerberos packet request from the client to the KDC TGT service - just a request for a service ticket.  The service ticket coming back containing the lifetime is encrypted.  One won't see the details of that in plain text over the wire.  These details explained in RFC 1510 and 4120.  Note:  If you run *klist* on one of the endpoints - client, KDC, or server you will see Kerberos ticket lifetimes in plaintext - but that is different - you are already on the host and using a specific tool to do so.